# Excel VBA - Deleting rows if not match from list

Tags: excel, vba

I have 2 sheets, Transfer Data and Keep List. My current code is below.

```
Dim cfind, cfind1, delete, c As Range
Dim x As String
Dim i, j As Integer
Set td = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Transfer Data")
Set delete = Range(cfind.Offset(0, 0), cfind.End(xlDown))
Set cfind = dl.Cells.Find(What:="Location Name", lookat:=xlWhole)
Set delete = Range(cfind.Offset(0, 0), cfind.End(xlDown))

j = td.Range("H2").End(xlDown).Row
For i = j To 1 Step -1
x = td.Cells(i, "H").value
Set cfind1 = delete.Find(What:=x, lookat:=xlWhole)
If cfind1 Is Nothing Then
td.Cells(i, "H").EntireRow.delete
End If
Next
```

So the idea of this is that whatever is on the Keep List (i.e. Column B on Keep List refers to Column H of Transfer Data, and if the value isnt on this Keep List, the entire row gets deleted.

My code works but it takes awhile, especially the initial run. for the rest of the column, I just re-use the code above and just adjusted the header name accordingly to what is on the Keep List, start with column B, then it works on the next list, which is Column C (Department Id).

Is there a more faster/efficient way to code this? Also there may be more columns added to the Keep List in the future, so flexibility to include future columns would also be helpful. The column headers for both tabs will be exactly the same but not necessarily in the same order.

**Transfer Data**
[image: Transfer Data]

**Keep List**
[image: Keep List]

Comment: Unless you gave us a fragment, your 5th line fails because cfind is not yet defined, and it is also repeated in the 7th line.  I don't see how "my code works" from just this example.  Also your problem statement is a little confusing - how are you supposed to know to start with column H & Transfer list and then automatically move on to column B and Department ID?

Comment: The slow speed is mostly due to all the worksheet accesses -- very slow.  For VBA, suggest you read your data and lists into VBA arrays; then create a third array with the results you need.  See the late Chip Pearsons's article on [VBA Arrays and Worksheet Ranges](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx) for useful information.  Or you could use Power Query (Available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Office 365, and do a Table.Join with multiple keys (corresponding to the columns you want to match), with a `JoinKind.RighOuter`  (or `Left` depending on which is the first table listed).